# PrimeNG table with virtualScroll not showing border around rows properly

Tags: angular, primeng, virtualscroll

I am using PrimeNG table with virtualScroll like so

```
  <p-table 
  [value]="filteredData" 
  scrollHeight="37rem" 
  [scrollable]="true" #tableEl 
  [virtualScroll]="virtualScroll"
  [virtualScrollItemSize]="53"
  selectionMode="single" 
  [(selection)]="selectedRow"
  dataKey="modelId"
  sortMode="multiple"
```

It renders the rows that are originally visible properly :
[image]

but the ones below that you need to scroll to get to are missing border around them:
[image]
Adding

```
styleClass="p-datatable"
```

or selecting another styleClass primeNG provides (p-datatable-scrollable) does not solve the problem. Adding my own style to the elements like for example

```
 <tr style="height:53px;border-bottom: 5px solid red;"
```

also does not help (only the first "page"/"buffer" is styled).
Removing virtualScroll does solve the problem (they all render with a border), but then it's slow which is why I need virtualScroll.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've also encountered this problem and the culprit was Tailwind.

Tailwind sets the table border to collapse by default.

I've fixed this by changing it to "separate"

> .p-datatable table {  border-collapse: separate; }

Comment: Bingo! That worked. Only had to add ::ng-deep  in front